# Range function in R giving "incorrect" range

Tags: r, range

I'm a R noob and am sorry to have to ask this question. I have a dataset loaded into R. There's a column named "Score".

I've made a variable named score.

```
score = as.integer(mydata$score)
```

There are values between 1 and 100 in that column. When I ask R

```
range(score)
```

I get 1 50. Similarly, when I use:

```
max(score)
```

I get 50... What have I done wrong?

Comment: please use `dput` to produce a [reproducible test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Almost certainly you are applying `as.integer` onto a factor column.  Try `as.integer(as.character(mydata$score))` to see if that fixes it.  That said, I wouldn't bet much on this unless you `dput` your data as @sds suggests.